# raspistill annotation timestamp not updating

Tags: camera, raspicam

When doing a timelapse, the annotation only shows the initial timestamp, not the current timestamp of each frame - which makes imho no sense? Am I doing something wrong? Is there any quick workaround?

```
raspistill -o /home/pi/sync/test/image_%04d.jpg --nopreview -tl 1000 -t 0 -a 12
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. While I do not know the internal workings of `raspistill` you can always use your own script to invoke it to take one image at any given time with a filename of your choosing. Essentially like [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/camera/raspicam/raspistill.md) (shown under "Bash script") thus getting the timestamp you'd like.

Answer (score 3):

Simple workaround using shell script. Example taking 10 pictures, 1 second apart. Change to accommodate for different needs.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

NUM=10
DELAY=1

while [ $NUM -gt 0 ]; do

    DATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M")
    raspistill -o /home/pi/camera/$DATE.jpg

    let NUM=NUM-1
    sleep $DELAY

done
```

Comment: +1. Thanks for the snippet - this is a reasonable workaround. Most importantly, the -a argument is now, as expected, working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel, you should update raspistill using apt-get.  The timestamp now updates on each captured image.